# Setting name attributes in material design

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-appcompat

I have a simple question, but I really don't get it. When we set a new style under material design, we use parent styles as follow:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

However, in some tutorials, I saw they insert the reference "android:" into the attribute, e.g.:

```
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

I know that the latter should be used for referencing every attribute in android, but I don't understand why in this case it is sometimes omitted and sometimes not.

Comment: `android:colorPrimaryDark` was introduced with api21.
You can use it with `Theme.Material`. With AppCompat theme you have to use the `colorPrimary` attribute

Answer (score 0):

It is omitted if you are using the [Android V7 Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7). In this case you use one of the Theme.AppCompat themes, instead of the Android theme. Take a look at [Maintaining Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is depending on which compatibility they want:

- using `android:` prefix they refer to a platform attribute, that is it will be effective only on devices where the attribute exist (e.g. API14+, API21+ etc)
- using without `android:` prefix they refer to an Appcompat Library's attribute linked with the app project, that is it will be effective on all devices with API 7+